# chain functions in second argument

Tags: r, functional-programming

Is there a simple way to chain functions in a way that a function is partially applied so that one argument remains and is then applied to one argument (not the first one) of another function before calling. (In my example: is there a simpler way of defining the function `three` given the functions `one` and `two`)

I tried to find solutions using magrittr and purrr but didn't come up with something simpler than just defining it as shown below.

```
one <- function(x,y){
  paste(x,y)
}

two <- function(x, y){
  x * y
}

three <- function(x,y){
  one(x, two(y, 3))
}

three(1,2)

# [1] "1 6"
```

Comment: What about i.e. using the base R pipe? `three <- function(x,y){
  two(y, 3) |> 
    one(x, y = _)
}
`?

Comment: I was thinking about something without the `three <- function(x,y)` part. Like with the `.` placeholder for the magrittr pipe when used on the lhs of the pipe. But as far as I know this only works for the first argument of `one`.

But good to Know about the `_` placeholder. I hope IT updates my R version soon, I'm still on 4.1.

Comment: I am not aware of a use-case where `.` is on the lhs of the formula. I am not sure i get what you mean by "But as far as I know this only works for the first argument of one."

Comment: Not in the lhs of a formula but in the lhs of a magrittr pipe. You could define a function `four <- . %>% one(2)` and then call it with one argument `four(1)`.  `four <- . %>% one(1, .)` would also work, but I cant chain a function before the second argument.

Answer (score 3):

The new [pipe operator](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/pipeOp.html) introduced in R 4.1 and the new placeholder introduced in R 4.2 are meant for this sort of problem.

```r
one <- function(x,y){
  paste(x,y)
}

two <- function(x, y){
  x * y
}

three <- function(x,y){
  y |>
    two(3) |>
    one(x, y = _)
}

three(1,2)
#> [1] "1 6"
```

<sup>Created on 2022-09-28 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

---

## Edit

Following the comment below, it is possible to bypass `three`:

```r
two(2, 3) |> one(1, y = _)
#> [1] "1 6"

2 |> two(3) |> one(1, y = _)
#> [1] "1 6"
```

<sup>Created on 2022-09-28 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

To see this, remember that the pipe operator transforms the first form below into the next ones.

```
h(g(f(x)))
f(x) |> g() |> h()
x |> f() |> g() |> h()
```

Or, with the functions in the question,

```
one(x, two(y, 3))
two(y, 3) |> one(x, y = _)
2 |> two(3, y = _) |> one(x, y = _)
```

A [R-Help thread starting here](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-devel/2022-April/081636.html) ends with [link](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-devel/2022-September/081959.html) to an excellent explanation by R Core Team member Prof. Luke Tierney is [this YouTube video](https://youtu.be/IMpXB30MP48).

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer, this is not what I was looking for, but still helps.

I was thinking about something without the `three <- function(x,y)` part. Like with the `.` placeholder for the magrittr pipe when used on the lhs of the pipe. But as far as I know this only works for the first argument of `one`.

But good to Know about the `_` placeholder. I hope IT updates my R version soon, I'm still on 4.1.

Answer (score 2):

The only way I see this to be possibly working would be to change the `two` function and add a third parameter to the `three` function:

```r
one <- function(x){
  paste(x[1], x[2])
}

two <- function(x){
  c(x[-c(2:3)], x[2] * x[3])
}

three <- . %>% 
  two %>% 
  one

three(c(1, 2, 3))
#[1] "1 6"
```

Comment: Thank you. This is another good solution, but in my case I don't have control over the signature of three, since it is passed to a function from another package. Guess I'll have to stay with manually defining the functions or doing something completely different.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand your goal right, according to your [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73877826/chain-functions-in-second-argument#comment130449628_73877894) you want to avoid `three()`. So, what about this:

```
one <- function(x, y) paste(x, y)
two <- function(x, y) x * y

#R4.2+
two(2, 3) |> one(x=1)
# [1] "1 6"

#R4.1+
two(2, 3) |> {\(.) one(., x=1)}()
# [1] "1 6"
```